# full_calendar change am/pm to 24 hours

Tags: fullcalendar

In the agenda week options on the left side - there is that am/pm I want to remove/replace that with just 01:00, 02:00 so on.

check out that example and switch to the week view - on the left side you will find 6am, 7am etc...

[fiddle](http://goo.gl/qF6OLO)

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the language pack [from here](http://fullcalendar.io/download/)

and then I've added this:

```
lang: "de",
```

to the full_calendar js code.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `timeFormat` option

> timeFormat: 'H(:mm)'

[TimeFormat Docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/timeFormat/)

Comment: For some reason, whenever I do this, it only changes the times for the meetings. Not the times to the left?